# Suboccipital Muscle Strain Migraine Solutions

Tags: pain, headache, migraine

I frequently lay on my stomach in bed to watch my TV. Because of this, my head is usually held "backwards". Lately this has been causing pounding, migraine-like tension headaches stemming from serious neck muscle pain. I'm looking for two solutions:
1.) Is there a quick way to relieve this? I'm trying 3-4x200mg ibuprofen and hot compresses from a microwaveable heat pack filled with some kind of straw. I also just tried adding a 200mg caffeine pill as well, as I read that can quicken the effects of the ibuprofen.

2.) Can anyone with working knowledge of the musculoskeletal system suggest a less physically demanding way to handle this activity? I've tried laying on my side, but that usually stresses one side or the other on my neck (either too many or too few pillows, I'm 6'4" with broad shoulders), and I can't seem to find a comfortable way to lay on my stomach.

I'm very concerned the effect that either the high ibuprofen dosage or painful laying position could have on my long term health.